# Diagonalizing Faddeev-Popov Lagrangian $U(1)$

Tags: gauge-theory, grassmann-numbers, brst, ghosts

How can we diagonalize the U(1) Faddeev-Popov Lagrangian in a consistent manner.
I can't seem to find any papers on this but I can't believe that they don't exist.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

**My own attempt**

$$S=\int dV -\partial_{\mu} \bar c \partial^\mu c \tag{1}$$
with $\bar c$ antihermitian and $c$ hermitian.

Obviously setting $\bar{c} = i(\phi_1 + \phi_2)$ and $c = \phi_1 - \phi_2$ diagonalized the action to:

$$S=\int dV -i((\partial \phi_1)^2 -(\partial \phi_2)^2) \tag{2}$$

With eg: $$\Pi_1 = \frac{\delta S}{\delta \partial \phi_1} = -i\partial \phi_1 \tag{3}$$ such that the commutation relations become:

$$\{\phi_1(x),-i\partial \phi_1(y)\} = i\delta(x-y)\tag{4}$$

such that $$\{a_1(k), a_1(k')^\dagger\} \sim i \delta(k-k')\tag{5}$$

Such that $$\langle a|a\rangle = \langle 0|aa^\dagger|0\rangle \sim i \tag{6}$$

That I cannot understand since the original theory did not have any states with negative norm... Also if I calculate the Hamiltonian I find that it is imaginairy.

Comment: Comment to the post (v3): The crossterms are missing in eq. (2).

Comment: Yes indeed, I oversaw the fact that they don't cancel due to them being Grasmann variables. There go my hopes and dreams of diagonalizing it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a slightly different perspective: OP's question seems to (possibly indirectly) inquire whether a quadratic ghost action term of the form $$\bar{c}_i ~M^i{}_j~ c^j,\tag{i}$$ 
where $M^i{}_j$ is a (possible infinite-dimensional) matrix,
can be recast into an action term of the form
$$ \frac{1}{2} C^I ~A_{IJ}~ C^J~? \tag{ii}$$
Here $A_{IJ}$ is an **antisymmetric** matrix, due to the Grassmann nature of the $C$'s.

Since OP's matrix (or rather operator) $M=\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}$ is **symmetric** to begin with, this endeavour is a lost cause/impossible.

Comment: Wonderful ! This is great, exactly what I needed...
(Or didn't need but hey physics doesn't always do what you want does it :) )

Comment: However may I still add to this that $H = \omega\bar{c^\dagger}c +h.c. $ is diagonal when acting on states since $\{c, c^\dagger\}= 1$ and $cc=\bar{c}\bar{c}=0$. Indeed we could write $H = \omega|\bar{c}\rangle\langle c| + h.c.$ such that e.g. $H = \omega|\bar{c}\rangle\langle c| \bar{c}\rangle = |\bar{c}\rangle$. This migth be worth adding to your answer for later people to read  ?

Bottomline is that $c$ and $\bar{c}$ form a null basis with this in mind the action is in fact diagonal.

Comment: Thanks @gertian. I prefer to keep this answer short not to muddle my main point. Consider to add your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

There's one serious flaw in your entire strategy. Since $\overline{c},\,c$ are fermions, they are Grassmann-number-valued. Thus any complex numbers $w,\,z$ satisfy $(w\overline{c}+zc)^2=0$. You therefore can't rewrite the result in the manner you intended. More precisely, if $\phi=w\overline{c}+zc$ then $$\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi=g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\phi\partial_\nu\phi=g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu(w\overline{c}+zc)\partial_\nu(w\overline{c}+zc),$$which vanishes because Grassmann numbers anticommute.

Comment: Does this mean that it is impossible to diagonalize the Lagrangian or is there still another possible trick ?
I was thinking to denote $i\phi_1 = $\tilde \phi_1$$ could you do something with that ?

Comment: @gertian You can't diagonalise products of Grassmann numbers. However, you can use the familiar form of the Lagrangian to derive momenta, EOMs etc. The interesting finding is that the EOM obtained by varying one fermion is a constraint on the other fermion.

Comment: Thanks again, it turns out that I was looking at my problem from the "wrong angle" your comment got me out of there. Now I found what I was searching for !
That's going to be a great contribution to my masters thesis :)

Comment: The ghosts, $\bar{c}$ and $c$, are actually scalars with anticommuting statistics, they are not fermions as they are spin 0.

Comment: @CStarAlgebra It depends on whether you define bosons and fermions by their spin or statistics, but the latter makes more sense because the statistics are named for the same scientists and the spin-based naming is inspired by the usual connection between the two for physical particles. There's no point naming F-D stats satisfiers after Bose.